# Context API Consumer value is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a grandchild components which consumer from their grandparent. However, the context value is undefined:

File1:

```
export const WTContext = createContext();

export default class A extends Component {

    ...
    render(){
        ...
        const contextValue={state: { items: [] }, actions: { doA: () => {}}}
        return (
            <WTContext.Provider value={contextValue} >
                ...
            </WTContext.Provider>
        }
    }
}
```

File2:

```
export default function B(){
  return (
     <WTContext.Consumer>
        {({state}) => (
          ...
          return (
             <div>
                {state.items.map(...<C/>)} //all good, B use context.
             </div>
             {state.items
          )
        )}
     </WTContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

File3:

```
export default function C(props){
   return (
       <WTContext.Consumer>
           {({ state, actions }) => {
                // <-- Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
                ...

           }
       </WTContext.Consumer>
   )
}
```

So The mapping in `B`, that renders multiple `C` components, has context consumer value `undefined`.
The imports are valid, but I can't figure out why the value that the provider passes is `undefined` on a 2nd level of nesting (since the first level seems fine, `B` it Does uses the context as requested).

Comment: Probably in component C the Context is not imported correctly. I created a demo codesandbox to illustrate working nested Consumers https://codesandbox.io/s/r79ym626no. Could you create a reproducible demo of your issue

Comment: Actually is does imported correctly. When I debug on chrome, the iteration show the actions and state values as expected. But as I release the debugger, I get the error. So annoying, ridiculous.
Speaking of prev implementation, when used (context)..

Comment: Probably its an issue where you some mutation override the context value to null, if you can create a reproducible demo, I can try to debug your issue

Comment: Updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c7bqpeyn/3/, works for me nested.

Answer (score 0):

create context using `React.createContext()`

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    // Create new context
    export const MyContext = React.createContext();

    export class MyProvider extends Component {

        render() {
            const contextValue={state: { items: [] }, actions: { doA: () => {}}}

            return (
                <MyContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
                   .....
                </MyContext.Provider>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it works in Component B, the other person has definitely import createContext as a named import from React

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Apparently it was a 3rd party issue. I used google-map-react library, and noticed they removed the support for Context API for those who use React version < 15, and release the fix on the next major release.